# How to extract data after a field in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have following text in a  file

```
 "rules": [
        "/Common/Tetration_TCP_L4_ipfix",
        "/Common/_sys_https_redirect"
    ],
    "rulesReference": [
        {
            "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/rule/~Common~Tetration_TCP_L4_ipfix?ver=12.0.0"
        }
```

want to extract anything inside `"rules": []`
currently it is

```
/Common/Tetration_TCP_L4_ipfix
/Common/_sys_https_redirect
```

Output should look like

```
Tetration_TCP_L4_ipfix
_sys_https_redirect
```

but again this can be anything.

Answer (score 4):

If your input file contains non full-fledged JSON but only inner fragment (though structurally valid) you may recover the missing "outer" parts to get a full valid JSON structure.

**`sed`** + **`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.rules[] | sub("/Common/"; "")' <(sed '1 s/^/{/; $ s/$/]}/' file)
```

The output:

```
Tetration_TCP_L4_ipfix
_sys_https_redirect
```

---

Of course, if in real you have a valid JSON - just skip the `sed` processing and just use:

```
jq -r '.rules[] | sub("/Common/"; "")' file
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is a well-formed JSON file:

```
$ jq -r '..|select(type=="object" and has("rules")).rules|map(split("/")|.[-1])|.[]' file.json
Tetration_TCP_L4_ipfix
_sys_https_redirect
```

This will use `jq` to recursively find all the JSON objects that has a `rules` key.  For all the array values of those keys, it will split the value on `/` and return the last component of it.

Answer (score 3):

Using **AWK:**

```
awk -F '[/"]' '/"rules": /,/],/{if(/"rules": |],/) next; print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
```